# Hibernate PostgreSQL what a mess with auto generated increment code field?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

Hibernate created the table in existing database for jobLifeTime entity, but it given to first record auto generated code started with 8781, instead of 0. This table have foreign key to other object (scraperTask), that stored in DB right before jobLifeTime entity object, and hibernate given a code 8780 to scraperTask record (this clear because table with scraperTask already have some records).

Why hibernate use increment count for jobLifeTime.code from scraperTask.code?

**Update**
*Looks like Hibernate or PostgreSQL use one number sequence for both tables primary keys. It this right behavior?*

Here java classes and screenshot from database table:

[image: jobLifeTime table - job_chron_stg]

```
@Entity
@Table(name="job_chron_stg", indexes = {  @Index(name = "job_life_time_code_hidx", columnList = "code"),
        @Index(name = "job_life_time_job_id_hidx", columnList = "job_id")})
public class JobLifeTime {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)   
    private Long code;
    @Column(name="job_id", length=24)
    private String targetJobCode;
    @ManyToOne()
    private ScraperTask scraperTask;
    @Column(name="salary_low")
    private Integer salaryMin;
    @Column(name="salary_high")
    private Integer salaryMax;
    @Column(name="scrape_timestamp")
    private Date scrapeTimestamp;
    @Column(name="remove_timestamp")
    private Date removeTimestamp;

    public JobLifeTime(){}

    public JobLifeTime(Element node, ScraperTask scraperTask){
        targetJobCode = node.attr("data-jk");
        this.scraperTask = scraperTask;
        salaryMin = scraperTask.getSalaryMin();
        salaryMax = scraperTask.getSalaryMax();
        scrapeTimestamp = new Date();       
    }
//getters-setters
}
```

scraperTask class

```
@Entity
@Table(indexes = { @Index(name = "scraper_task_code_hidx", columnList = "code"),
        @Index(name = "task_start_at_hidx", columnList = "task_start_at")})
public class ScraperTask {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long code;
    @Column(name="task_start_at")
    private Date taskStartAt;
    private Date taskCompleteAt;
    private String description;
    @Transient
    private Integer salaryMin;
    @Transient
    private Integer salaryMax;
    //@Transient
    private Integer websiteJobsNumber;
    @Transient
    private String firstResponse;
    //@Transient
    //private Integer processedNodes;
    //@Transient
    private Boolean doneSuccessfully;
    @Transient
    private List<JobLifeTime> scrapedJobLifeTimeList;
    @Transient
    private List<Job> scrapedJobList;
    @Transient
    private KeywordsEntity keywordsEntity;
    @Transient
    private String category;

    protected ScraperTask(){
    }

    public ScraperTask(String uriString, Integer salaryMin, Integer salaryMax){
        description = uriString;
        taskStartAt = new Date();
        this.salaryMin = salaryMin;
        this.salaryMax = salaryMax;
        websiteJobsNumber=0;
        //processedNodes = 0;
        doneSuccessfully = false;
        scrapedJobLifeTimeList = new LinkedList<JobLifeTime>();
        scrapedJobList = new LinkedList<Job>();
    }
//getters-setters
}
```

Comment: use GenerationType.IDENTITY with postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be in control of your generated values, use a Postgresql sequence object and declare it in your entity object correctly.

That said, internal, auto-generated primary keys shouldn't care what the values are because, for the most part, they should not be exposed outside the application and should only be used to simply foreign keys (i.e., instead of having a multipart PK replicated in many remote tables).  With sequence number caching, there's no guarantee that gaps won't exist or that values are strictly in order (for example, different database connections might have cached different values, but you might not know which connection is used for each insert, therefore not guaranteeing strictly increasing values)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to truncate jobLifeTime table. This table doesn't have records yet right.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE jobLifeTime
```

Comment: Could you explain why? I can drop table, delete from table, truncate ... anything but cannot understand how it could solve the issue with code increment mess? The table was not exist when hibernate create it and begin fill with data

Comment: Ok, try changing: strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY.